# Open datagrid items in a new window

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a page in my WPF application containing 3 datagrids. For space reasons, the height of these datagrids is not too long. The solution it comes to my mind is adding a button next to each datagrid and open a new window full size with the datagrid items. Here my two questions:
a) What do you think about this solutions? Have you ever faced a similar problem and how have you solved it?
b) In order to implement the solution I propose, is there an easy way to bind the items source of new datagrid to the items source of the old datagrid without creating all the bindings of each column and implementint again all the Add / Delete / Modified methods? I want the new datagrid behaving like a magnifying glass of the old datagrid. This means, if after the new datagrid is created, a new item is added, deleted or modified from the old datagrid, the new datagrid should be updated. 
The datagrid has also some input fields. So if a field is modified in the new datagrid, I want the old datagrid to be updated. 
Will I get this behaviour just by binding the new datagrid ItemsSource to the old datagrid ItemsSource?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just make some buttons that will expand one data grid and collapse the others, or just use a [GridSplitter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridsplitter(v=vs.110).aspx)? It's as simple as putting them inside a Grid and manipulating row or column sizes, there's no need to make more windows and data grids.

Comment: thanks for you comment @icebat. This is the solution I have at the moment. But I couldn´t find a way to define a mínimum height for every datagrid. It is posible to expand a datagrid by a grid splitter hiding completely the other datagrids which is not very handy. I would like to set a mínimum height for all the grids of p.e. 30 pixels

Comment: If you use Grid, just set [min height](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.rowdefinition.minheight(v=vs.110).aspx) for rows that contain the data grids.

Comment: I tried so but didn't work

Comment: Then you did something wrong. Check details of [GridSplitter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridsplitter(v=vs.110).aspx) usage to make sure. Setting RowDefinition.MinHeight is enough if GridSplitter is done correctly.

Comment: It works now. thanks. Don´t know what I was doing wrong